# DJango Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'django_session'

Tags: django, django-models, pyodbc, django-2.1

Need help with setting up my django project. 
my settings.py :

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
    'NAME': 'DCMS_DEV',
    'HOST': 'sql1165-xx-in.xxx.xxx.xxx.com,4567',
    'USER': 'sakshi',
    'PASSWORD': 'sakshi123',

    'OPTIONS': {
        'driver': "ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server",
    }
}
}
```

This is the error when i pass through admin:

```
ProgrammingError at /admin/login/
('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'django_session'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW); [42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/
Django Version: 2.1.12
Exception Type: ProgrammingError
Exception Value:    
('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'django_session'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW); [42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")
```

I am new bee for django. can you tell me what all basic requirement which are needed to run an django project?
how do i resolve this?

Comment: did you run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: python   manage.py migration was giving some other error which i resolved it by running manage.py migration --fake  then did python manage.py makemigrations and python manage.py migration. 
after that i started getting this error

Comment: did you run `manage.py migration --fake` for the first migration?

Comment: First i did manage.py migration which gave some error then i did manage.py migration --fake

Comment: i guess then there is no `django-session` in your db. `django-session` is created when you run `migrate` for the first time. what error did you get when you run migrate without `--fake`?

Comment: there were some tables which got created when i tried with --fake. when i tried running migrate without --fake i am seeing this error.. 
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ('42S01', "[42S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]There is already an object named 'django_
content_type' in the database. (2714) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Comment: i will suggest you to delete that db, and create a new one. and dont use --fake for the first migration.

Comment: There is already a db session present in dbaas. i was trying to connect to that session.. cannot delete that instance.. Is there any thing i can do other than deleting the database?

Answer (score 0):

After manage.py makemigrations, I did manage.py migrate --fake appname (where appname is your application`s name) and after I did one more time manage.py migrate and it worked. Hope it will help somebody one day :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got the same error because of simple mistake as a beginner.
Instead of running
python manage.py makemigrations
I typed
python manage.py migrate.
So the table was not created then and the error meant just that it couldn't find the table where to insert the values.